# How to get file list from specific folder from remote server in C#?

Tags: c#, ftp

I want to get list of files from specific folder of the remote server. Currently, I can get list of files and folder using following code. There is a folder "SoftwareUpdate" in this list. I want to get file list of "SoftwareUpdate" folder.

Here is my current code:

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.abc.com/");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;

// This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("testuser", "test123");
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    String filename = reader.ReadLine();
}
```

Can anybody suggest me how to get list of files of specific folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change the first line to ...

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.abc.com/SoftwareUpdate/");
```